# Remote Event Receiver - Declare Item as Record looses field values when declared (CSOM Provider Hosted Add-In)

Tags: csom, sharepoint-on-prem, provider-hosted-app, content-approval, records-management

this solution is in **SharePoint 2016 On Premise**.
I have activated **content approval** on document libraries and the RER's I have in my app is handling these events:

- "ItemAdded"
- "ItemUpdated"
- "ItemAdding"
- "ItemUpdating"
- "ItemCheckingOut"
- "ItemDeleting"

In the "ItemUpdading" event I keep track on when a document has been approved or rather when a document is sent to be approved.

```
// After = "vti_doclibmodstat" Before = "vti_docstoreversion" Standard = "_ModerationStatus"
// 0 = The list item is approved.
// 1 = The list item has been denied approval.
// 2 = The list item is pending approval.
// 3 = The list item is in the draft or checked out state.
// 4 = The list item is scheduled for automatic approval at a future date.

// 2 = The list item is pending approval.
if (currentModStat == "2")
{
    // 0 = The list item is approved.
    if (afterModStat == "0")
    {
        // Make sure the current user is the same as the one specified in the field "DocumentApprover"
        if (currentUserLoginName != currentDocApprover.LoginName)
        {
            result.ErrorMessage = "Du får bara godkänna dokument där du står som \"Godkännare\"";
            result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.CancelWithError;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // Set User and Date of the approval
            var dateStr = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
            result.ChangedItemProperties.Add("ApprovedBy", fuvDocApprover.LookupId);
            result.ChangedItemProperties.Add("ApprovedDate", dateStr);
            result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.Continue;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The solution is working quite well but there's one odd problem when working with newer Office files and declaring them as records through CSOM and manually via GUI.

```
// Declare item as record
Records.DeclareItemAsRecord(clientContext, listItem);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

The fields I have trouble with:

- StaticName="ApprovedBy" DisplayName="Godkänt av"
- StaticName="ApprovedDate" DisplayName="Godkänt datum"

These are custom fields within the list template that I use for document libraries. When a document is in the final stage of approval the "ItemUpdating" event is passing on "ChangedItemProperties" and this works fine with older files but when declaring newer files the values vanishes.

[image: The images shows two documents that has been declared as records with CSOM.]

If I pause with debugger in Visual Studion on the last line below

```
Records.DeclareItemAsRecord(clientContext, listItem);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I can refresh my browser and see that the values are there, however if I then press F5 and execute the query, the "lock" gets applied, item is declared as record but **the values disappears.**

I think this might have something to do with system language (LCID 1033) as I can still see the values in SharePoint Management Shell when fetching the list item.
I have changed the LCID to 1053 in PowerShell before by changing the current threads culture but no luck doing so in C#.

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated!